# How do I make Eureka client to use host machine's IP instead of Docker container's IP?

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to dockerize my SpringBoot application. When the application is deployed in the docker container, it gets registered with Eureka using the docker container's IP.

I want it to get registered with the host machine's IP.

I've set `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress` to `true`. I tried ignoring the network interfaces like it is mentioned in [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/multi/multi__spring_cloud_commons_common_abstractions.html#ignore-network-interfaces), but had no luck with it.

Is there any way to tell Eureka client to use host machine's IP?

Answer (score 3):

If you start you container with `--network=host`, your container will have host's ip address and you wont need any additional configuration. Like `docker run -it --network=host you-container ...`

But consider drawbacks of this mode like lack of isolation of container, because your container will have access to host's networking.